# block .exe inside a .zip

Tags: linux, firewall, zip, squid

If we want to block an extension in our firewall, we can use a rule similar to this:

```
example iptables rules:
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m string --string ".exe" --algo bm -j DROP
```

Or we can do it in our proxy with a rule similar to this:

```
example squid-cache rules:
acl blext url_regex -i "blext.txt"
http_access deny blext
acl blmime rep_mime_type -i "blmime.txt"
http_reply_access deny blmime
```

Where blmime and blext ACLs contain the following (source [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)):

```
blext.txt
\.exe([a-zA-Z][0-9]*)?(\?.*)?$
\.zip([a-zA-Z][0-9]*)?(\?.*)?$
\.rar([a-zA-Z][0-9]*)?(\?.*)?$
etc

blmime.txt
^application/exe$
^application/zip$
^application/octet-stream$
etc
```

**My question is:**

How can I block a .zip or .rar extension, which contains (inside) an .exe file?

PD: I can not block .rar or .zip, since it would generate false positives, because there are legitimate downloads that do not contain .exe or .bat inside the containers

Comment: Well firstly, you appear to be blocking based on file names, which is just .... bad. It's not hard to name a file something else, zip it up, send it, rename it... So just block all zip files if you must.

Comment: What you propose generates false positives, since there are legitimate zip and rar

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following link and block extension in squid proxy.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/squid-content-filter-block-files/

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is not what I'm asking